# MEF 4.0 Constructor Dependency Injection without attributes on the constructor

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, mef

I have the following code in a library:

```
public interface IFirst { }
public interface ISecond { }
public class Second : ISecond
{
    public Second(IFirst injectedFirstService)
    {
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to specify in a MEF container that the `ISecond` interface should be provided to other parts with an instance of `Second`, built with dependency injection.

I would also like to do it in a way that does not force me to put an attribute inside of the library class (that is, no `ImportingConstructor` in the `Second` class).

I know of the following solutions:

- Use a subclass of second or a class that decorates `Second` but still implements the same `ISecond` interface, but with the appropriate MEF attributes. These types could then be exposed in a composition catalog.
- Write a MEF attributed part that basically translates the constructor imports and the instance export as property imports and exports, in the following way, to be put in a `CompositionBatch` instance:

  ```
  public class SecondExporter
  {
      [Import] IFirst First { get; set; }
      [Export] ISecond Second { get { return new Second(First); } }
  }
  ```

What else can I do?

Comment: Since you do not use .NET 4.5, you could download MEF2 Preview 5 from https://mef.codeplex.com/releases/view/79090 and use the MEF2 Conventions feature. With MEF Convetions you can set all the imports/exports imperatively. If you decide to try this approach let me know and I can add a full answer with code.

Comment: I would like to see a solution for this question also. Are there any issues with the MEF2 preview in terms of performance?